# One path operation is ignored if the paths are the same, but one of them has query parameters

Tags: python, rest, backend, fastapi

I'd like to have two path operations with the same path `@app.get("/movies/", ..)`:

```
@app.get("/movies/", response_model=schemas.Movie)
def read_movie_by_title(title: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_movie = crud.get_movie_by_title(db, title=title)
    return db_movie


@app.get("/movies/", response_model=List[schemas.Movie])
def read_movies(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_movies = crud.get_movies(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return db_movies
```

As You can see, the first one is for getting a movie by its title and has a query parameter (`title`) and the second one is for getting a list. When I check the generated docs, the one for `read_movie_by_title` is missing.

I tried to solve this by changing the path for `read_movie_by_title` to `/movies` by removing `/`, but I don't like this solution at all.

So the question is: Is there a way to have two equal paths, but one with query parameters, or do I need to do this in a different way? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Path Parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#path-parameters) instead of Query parameters for the first one, by changing the endpoint to `"/movies/{title}"`:

```py
@app.get("/movies/{title}", response_model=schemas.Movie)
def read_movie_by_title(title: str, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_movie = crud.get_movie_by_title(db, title=title)
    return db_movie

# 2nd remains the same
@app.get("/movies/", response_model=List[schemas.Movie])
def read_movies(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_movies = crud.get_movies(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return db_movies
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question (Is there a way to have two equal paths, but one with query parameters) is no, the only way to differentiate a path is by its method (`GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, ...`).

You do however have multiple ways of achieving your desired result.

## REST approach

The standard `REST` approach to this would be to define a different path for the **title** based retrieval, such as `/movies/{title}`, like in the first example shown in the documentation for [path parameters @ FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/).

If you want to implement a `search` feature instead of a direct `retrieval by unique title` method, you can do something like this:

```py
@app.get("/movies", response_model=List[schemas.Movie])
def read_movies(title: Optional[str] = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    # list of filters
    filters = []
    if title: # if it's not none
        filters.append(models.Movie.title.ilike(f"%{title}%"))
    
    db_movies = crud.get_movies(db, filters=filters, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return db_movies
```

and within your crud operation you would query it something like:

```py
    return session.query(models.Movie).filter(*filters).all()
```

## Simpler approach that does what you want with one method

```py
@app.get("/movies", response_model=List[schemas.Movie])
def read_movies(title: Optional[str] = None, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if title: # if it's not none
        return crud.get_movie_by_title(db, title=title)
    
    return crud.get_movies(db, filters=filters, skip=skip, limit=limit)
```

Though the latter might confuse the consumer of your API, hence the `REST` approach will be the most recommended one.